# Key at start or end of HMAC

Tags: hmac, attack

In the book Information Security Principles and Practice, the author explains why HMAC should be used for integrity with a symmetric key with the message, to prevent a MiTM to replace both the message and its MAC.

He explains why it is not secure to prepend the key to the message, with notation h(K, M). I don't understand how the attack works. Here's the paragraph:

> Suppose  we  choose  to  compute  an  HMAC  as  h(K,M).        Most 
>   cryptographic  hashes  hash  the  message  in blocks—for  MD5, SHA-1, 
>   and  Tiger,  the  block  size  is  512 bits.   As a result,  if M  = 
>   {B1,  B2),  where  each  Bi  is  512 bits, then  h(M)  =  F(F(A, B1),
>   B2) = F(h(B1), B2)                        (5.2)
>   for  some  function  F,   where  A  is  a  fixed  initial  constant.
>   For  example,  in  the  Tiger  hash,  the  function   F  consists  of 
>   the  outer  rounds  illustrated  in  Figure  5.2,   with  each  Bi 
>   corresponding  to  a  512-bit  block  of  input  and   A
>   corresponding  to  the  192-bit  initial  value   (a,b,c).
>
> If  Trudy  chooses  M'   so that  M' =
>   (M, X),     Trudy  might  be  able to use  equation (5.2)  to  find
>   h(K, M') from h(K, M)  without knowing  K since, for  K,  M,  and  X
>   of the  appropriate  size,   h(K,  M')  =  h(K,  M, X) = F(h(K, M),X),
>   where  the  function  F  is  known.

The last paragraph is the attack.

I don't understand, how does the attack work? How can Trudy find `h(K, M')` from `h(K, M)` without knowing K?

Comment: This is the length extension attack. Also, the hash functions pads the message before hashing. So one needs to consider {B1,B2} as padded message.

Comment: Could you also edit the quoted part to make it clear? the vvv's and 5,2 has no usage here. You can also add a picture for the figure.

Comment: @kelalaka edited; there is no picture

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic **length extension attack**. For hash functions like SHA-1 and SHA-2 the final **state** of hashing $h(K \| M)$ block by block is the output. If you hash $h(K \| M \| X)$ then you simply continue hashing from the given state (i.e. the last output).

In practice though the final block must contain a valid padding and length, which is added to $K \| M$. So basically you can create a valid hash for $K \| M \| P \| LE \| X$ where $P$ is the padding and $LE$ is the length encoding. You cannot just create *any* message that starts with $M$.

Comment: Length extension attacks are KMPLEX :P